# Where is the right place to store server files in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

In aws where is the best place to store files like user uploaded files or static files that will not cost much.

Normally what I do is to save the files in the ec2 server where i upload my code. I want to know if that is better or i should use s3 or move to elastic beanstack.

Comment: Amazon S3 is the most cost effective option

Comment: Elastic Beanstalk is effectively Amazon managed EC2 instances.  You'll still pay for the underlying EC2's.  S3 can be cheap, depending on your access needs but your post needs a great deal more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely Amazon S3. Reasons include:

- It is **separating compute from storage**. This way, you can launch more application servers, or replace failed servers, and the user files remain accessible in Amazon S3.
- Amazon S3 is a **regional service**, with data replicated between Availability Zones. Data stored on an instance in Amazon Block Storage (EBS) is kept in only one AZ.
- There are **no storage limits** in Amazon S3.
- It has a **lower cost** (S3 is around 2c/GB/month, EBS is around 10c/GB/month)
- Your application can provide links to objects stored in Amazon S3. Your users can then use these links to **access the objects directly from S3** without having to go via your web server. This reduces the load on your web server, which means you don't need to pay for larger instances. (There are many ways to secure your data in S3 so that only the right users can access it, such as using pre-signed URLs.)

These are just general recommendations. Your particular application might have non-standard needs.